# robot height navigation stack turtlebot

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap-2d, turtlebot-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a modified turtlebot that is more tall than the original turtlebot . The problem is that when I launch the navigation stack and I send a goal it works as I expected, but if in the path there are a obstacle like a table, the Turtlebot think that it can go under the table but the robot is more tall and the robot collides with the table.

My doubt is where is specified the height of the turtlebot for solve it.

Sorry if there are similar topics but, I've searched in the forums and I wasn't able to find it

Thanks in advance, Rubén Rodríguez.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/116936/robot-height-navigation-stack-turtlebot/) by [runix](https://answers.ros.org/users/10701/runix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2014-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After revise the navigation stack I found a solution for the problem, the navigation uses a costmap2d and it has a parameter called max_obstacle_height that is the maximum height of any obstacle to be inserted into the costmap in meters. After i change the value of the parameter the navigation stack works properly.

---

Originally posted by [runix](https://answers.ros.org/users/10701/runix/) with karma: 26 on 2014-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1